# OleDbDataAdapter: Check table existence?

Tags: c#, sql, oledbdataadapter

I have a program in C# that works with `.xls` files, where I query the database as below:

`SELECT * FROM [" +sheet + "$]`

If the sheet doesn't exist, the program crashes.

I need to first check if the table exists and if so, make some queries.

Is there any such option for `OleDbDataAdapter` or `SQL` when querying with `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetOleDbSchemaTable function. It's a bit obscure, but here's a link or two to some info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/180842/Reading-Excel-sheet-name-with-characters.aspx?display=PrintAll

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318452

Answer (score 0):

You can check shema (tables, views, etc...) via Connection.GetSchema - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934%28v=vs.80%29.aspx